# How to use AngularJS to store a 'Token' for the lifetime of the app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to login a user (using Restangular). The login controller gets returned a 'Token' which I then need to use on every request thereafter.

My question is, what is the best way to store this Token using AngularJS? It needs to exist for the lifetime of the app.

I was looking at services but I have to keep injecting it into the controllers on to keep it alive.

Comment: You can make use of $rootScope if you do not wish to implement services

Comment: @V31 is that a good idea to store the information there?

Comment: not a good idea to populate the global scope however you do not wish to use services

Comment: @V31 if i use a setter in a service would I make it last without having to set it on every controller again?

Comment: @Spike "Services" follow factory pattern and services are implemented as singleton object by angularjs, So every time your instantiate a new controller , Existing service object is returned by angular compiler.

Comment: @V31 ok so using a setter and getter patten in my case would actually work then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lifetime is not promise as far as you are using web apps, but if you want you can use localstorage,
here is an example service how to use localstorage in angular, you can add it to service.js file:

```
var storeService = innovidServices.factory('storeService', function() {

    var service =
    {
        setClientData:function(client_details)
        {
            window.localStorage.setItem( "client_data", JSON.stringify(client_details) );
            client_data = client_details;
        },
        getClientData:function()
        {
            if (client_data == null)
            {
                client_data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("client_data"));
            }
            return client_data;
        }
    }

    var client_data = null;

    return service;
});
```

Comment: Thats a good idea. I should have said however this 'web app' will be access on a mobile device. Does this this work say on a iPad or iPhone?

Comment: yes, if it's in browser, if you wrap it on phonegap or something else, you need to use phonegap api then you will have an access to store it on the phone itself and not on the browser.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is store this 'Token' in the $rootScope.

```
myapp.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    ...
    $rootScope.token = Token;
    ...
});
```

Then use http interceptor to inject this as for example GET parameter to every query

```
myapp.factory('httpTokenInterceptor', function ($rootScope) {
  return {
    request: function (config) {
      var token = $rootScope.token;
      if (token) {
          config.url =  URI(config.url).addSearch({'token':token}).toString();
      }
      return config;
    }
  };
});

myapp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpTokenInterceptor');
});
```